# VS Code : find next occurrence shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, find

I'm looking for a shortcut to find the next occurrence via the find in current file search box. I cannot seem to find anything other than pressing <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> once in the box. This is highly inefficient and I am used to using Text Mate on the Mac where I can do `cmd-g` to find the next occurrence. I'm shocked I cannot find someone else looking for this type of functionality in VS Code. There is the global search <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut, but what if I don't want global search?

I tried google searching for an answer and was unable to find one. The best solution so far is <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly. Had to disable to auto insert of current string functionality to even get this far. There is <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> which you can utilize, but requires the search term to be selected for it to find the next.

Comment: Once you've searched and found the first occurrence, just press "F3" ?!? That seems to work just fine ... see [VS Code keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for explanations and ways to change that to your liking